# Symfony2 highcharts, change color

Tags: javascript, symfony, highcharts

I'm using this bundle https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle for create some charts with Symfony2.

I have created a pie chart but i don't know how can i change the color of a part ? you can have an example and jsfiddle  here : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

If i need to change the color of the firefox part, how can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the default Highchart's theme or create a new one.

Look at the design documentation to see how to do it http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes

You need to edit the `colors` option at the beginning of the theme to modify serie's colors.